# Something strange happens with the redirects

Tags: javascript, redirect

Good, I had a code in which I tried to make a redirect, but these did not work, it seemed to refresh only the page, but it did not redirect.

I have simplified the code to see if something conflicted out of desperation to the world that I have left a function with only a redirect, and the same thing is still happening. Running the function appears to refresh the page, but does not redirect it.

All this does not redirect me (I put the google web example)
I have tried the following options individually but only one of them works

```
function sendForm(){

    window.location.href = "http://www.google.es"; // DONT WORK
    location.href = "http://www.google.es"; // DONT WORK
    location.assign("http://www.google.es"); // DONT WORK
    $(location).attr('href', "http://www.google.es"); // DONT WORK
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.es"); // DONT WORK

    window.open("http://www.google.es"); // YEEEEES WORK
    window.open("http://www.google.es","_self"); //  DONT WORK

}
```

Only works for me window.open I have tried to set the _self parameter to simulate the same action but in that case it does not work.

It looks like the page refreshes but the redirect does not.

I also put the html code in case the error is there

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Login page</title>
<!-- Bootstrap grid -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap grid -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleLogin.css">
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive logo" id="logotipo" src="logotres.png" alt="">
    <form name="login" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="User">
        <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
        <button id="send" onclick="sendForm()">Enter</button>
        <div class="moreoptions">
            <div class="ico">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <a href="#">I forgot my password</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ico">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <a href="#">Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a little frustrated because I can not find out why this does not work

Comment: Seriously though, does this not work in every browser?

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Judging by the name you want to submit the form then redirect the page, probably based on response from the server. Why complicate matters when you could submit the form and let the server send the correct redirect without JS?

Comment: I have simplified the code but the code that will be sent is one json for post method with ajax, and in the callback success the redirect will go, but obviously it does not work either

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

`window.location = 'http://google.es'`;

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, only had to add in the HTML to the BUTTON of the form submission "type =" button "